# Simple Bidirectional @OneToOne store null

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

I try to follow the [@OneToOne bidrectional example](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-one-bidirectional) from documetation but I always have a null reference in the PhoneDetails phone_id colum, and obtein a Phone with null details when do a get.

I follow the documentation creating Phone and PhoneDetails Classes as is say.

But because the documentation don't specify how to test and I need to develop an Spring Boot app, I create one to test and maybe, in any step of this I have the error.

Here are my steps, and [the code I update to github](https://github.com/soyjuanmedina/oneToOne) hoping someone can review it

1 - Create a Spring Boot App in Eclipse with Spring tool suite with Java Version 8

2 - Add dependencies MySqlDriver and Spring Web

3 - Add dependency in the pom to spring-boot-starter-data-jpa

4 - Create packages under the main package (com.onetoone) for models, controllers and repository

5 - Create in the model package the classes Phone y PhoneDetails as say in documentation
package com.onetoone.models;

```
@Entity(name = "Phone")
public class Phone {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "`number`")
    private String number;

    @OneToOne(
        mappedBy = "phone",
        cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
        orphanRemoval = true,
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY
    )
    private PhoneDetails details;

    //Getters and setters are omitted for brevity

    public void addDetails(PhoneDetails details) {
        details.setPhone( this );
        this.details = details;
    }

    public void removeDetails() {
        if ( details != null ) {
            details.setPhone( null );
            this.details = null;
        }
    }
}

@Entity(name = "PhoneDetails")
public class PhoneDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String provider;

    private String technology;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "phone_id")
    private Phone phone;

    //Getters and setters are omitted for brevity

}
```

In documentation they create this classes as static, but I have to remove it because Eclipse says: "Illegal modifier for the class Phone; only public, abstract & final are permitted".
I import all the anotations (@Entity, @Id...) from javax.persistence.

6 - Create interface PhoneController in his package

```
package com.onetoone.repository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;   
import com.onetoone.models.Phone;

public interface PhoneRepository extends JpaRepository<Phone, Long> {
}
```

7 - Create PhoneController

```
package com.onetoone.controllers;

import java.util.Optional;  
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;  
import com.onetoone.models.Phone;
import com.onetoone.repository.PhoneRepository;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/phone")
public class PhoneController {
    
    @Autowired
    PhoneRepository phoneRepository;
    
    @PostMapping("/save")
    public  ResponseEntity<Boolean> savePhone(@RequestBody Phone phone) {
        phoneRepository.save(phone);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(true);
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/get")
    public ResponseEntity<Optional<Phone>> getPhone(@RequestBody int i) {

        Long id = Long.valueOf(i);
        Optional<Phone> phone = phoneRepository.findById(id);

        return ResponseEntity.ok(phone);
    }

}
```

8 - Set the application.properties in his file under src/main/resources

```
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test?serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username= root
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect= org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= update
```

I have to add the ?serverTimezone=UTC to the database url to avoid an error.

9 - Create an schema in my local database called test

10 - Start the app with Spring Boot Dashboard, and it create the tables 'phone' and 'phone_details' (also another one called 'hibernate_sequence')

11- I use postman to send a rest to this url http://localhost:8080/phone/save whit this body

```
{
  "number": "123-456-7890",
  "details": {
    "provider": "T-Mobile",
    "technology": "GSM"
  }
}
```

**12 - And here is the problem. It create an entry in the phone table (id, number)**

```
'1', '123-456-7890'
```

and other in the phone_details table (id, provider, technology, phone_id)

```
'2', 'T-Mobile', 'GSM', NULL
```

13 - Of course, if I do a post to url http://localhost:8080/phone/get with body 1 I recibe

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "number": "123-456-7890",
    "details": null
}
```

I hope anybody can help me because I try to reduce the code to the minimun to follow the documentation and still I have the issue :-(

The solution gives by @JavaMan is enought for the example, but not for a complex object. I hope someoneelse can help me!!!

Comment: Try something like:

`Phone phone = new Phone("123-456-7890");`
`PhoneDetail detail = new PhoneDetail("T-mobile", "GSM");`

`detail.setPhone(phone);`
`phone.setDetail(detail);`

`phoneRepository.save(phone); `

Comment: do you have the Cascade Annotation like this?
@OneToOne(
  mappedBy = "phone", 
  cascade = CascadeType.ALL, 
  orphanRemoval = true, 
  fetch = FetchType.LAZY)

Comment: Thanks @tashi, maybe its works, but it's not usefull with a very complex objects. I don't try it because I have to create all the constructors and as I say think is not the solution... but anywary I really apreciate your contribution.

Comment: Thanks @JavaMan, I I have added the code of the models to make it easier to see and as you can see the Cascade annotation is like you asked.

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52887653/onetomany-relationship-does-not-save-the-primary-key-of-the-parent-in-the-child ... maybe this will answer your question.

Comment: Thanks, @JavaMan I try it and in the controller, before save the phone do `phone.getDetails().setPhone(phone);` and works. To do the get I have to add @JsonIgnore annotation to the Phone in PhoneDetails. I think is strange have to do this and dificult in the complex objects, but at least works!!!! Thanks. If you want to put it in answers I select as correct one. If not I write by myself for people with same problem

Comment: @Ulises2010 I've added a short answer which should help others, unfortunately, I'm not able to explain it in detail.

Answer (score 0):

In your PhoneController, you have to add the line
phone.getDetails().setPhone(phone); otherwise the details object will not have a reference to the phone.

So like this

```
@PostMapping("/save")
public ResponseEntity<Boolean> savePhone(@RequestBody Phone phone) {
    phone.getDetails().setPhone(phone); 
    phoneRepository.save(phone);
    return ResponseEntity.ok(true);
}
```

Also, to get the code running add the `@JsonIgnore` annotation to your Phone field in your PhoneDetails class.

Comment: This is  is enought for the example, but not for a complex object. I hope someoneelse can help me!!!